# Multiple layer XML to CSV

Tags: python, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

I struggle to find a way to convert the XML file to CSV by python. This file has multiple attributes which I need to have in dataframe.
Here is the example of XML file:

```
<helpdesk-tickets type="array">
---<helpdesk-ticket>
------<account-id type="integer">123</account-id>
---<notes type="array">
------<helpdesk-note>
---------<body>content 1 I need</body>
------</helpdesk-note>
------<helpdesk-note>
---------<body>content 2 I need</body>
------</helpdesk-note>
---</notes>
---</helpdesk-ticket>
---<helpdesk-ticket>
------<account-id type="integer">456</account-id>
---<notes type="array">
------<helpdesk-note>
---------<body>content 3 I need </body>
------</helpdesk-note>
------<helpdesk-note>
---------<body>content 4 I need </body>
------</helpdesk-note>
---</notes>
---</helpdesk-ticket>
</helpdesk-tickets>
```

This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd
  
cols = ["account-id","notes"]
rows = []
  
xmlparse = Xet.parse('E:\python\Tickets132.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

for i in root:
    display_id = i.find("account-id").text
  
for att in root.findall('./helpdesk-ticket/notes/helpdesk-note'):
    notes2 = att.find("body").text 
    
    
    rows.append({
                "account-id": display_id,
                "notes" : notes2,
                })
  
df91 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
display (df91)
df91.to_csv('output21.csv')
```

This is what I get:

```
account-id  notes
0   123 content 1 I need
1   123 content 2 I need
2   123 content 3 I need
3   123 content 4 I need
```

The expected output:

```
account-id  notes
    0   123 content 1 I need
    1   123 content 2 I need
    2   456 content 3 I need
    3   456 content 4 I need
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please correct your code as `for` loop is not complete line: `for att in`

Comment: Thanks, I did edit, it's a typo error when I post the code here, do you have suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you firstly iterate over **account-id** over whole file and then again with **helpdesk-note**. You need nested loop.

This should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd

cols = ["account-id", "notes"]
rows = []

xmlparse = Xet.parse('E:\python\Tickets132.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

for helpdesk_ticket in root.findall("./helpdesk-ticket"):   # iteration over every helpdesk_ticket
    display_id = helpdesk_ticket.find("account-id").text    # save account-id

    for helpdesk_note in helpdesk_ticket.findall(".//helpdesk-note"):    # find every helpdesk-note in iterated helpdesk_ticket
        notes2 = helpdesk_note.find("./body").text   # find body text
        rows.append({
            "account-id": display_id,
            "notes": notes2,
        })

df91 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
display(df91)
df91.to_csv('output21.csv')
```

Comment: @AlexK thanks for your remind, I'm new on this site then many things need to pay attention.